# 400 Bad Request Nestful Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to use the [Pocket API](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication) to authorize my application. So I'm using [Nestful](https://github.com/maccman/nestful) to send HTTP requests. And everytime I try sending a request I get a `400 Bad Request`. The Pocket documentation says that it could be that it's either a missing consumer key or a missing redirect url.

But now I'm looking at the network tab in Chrome and it says that there is a 500 Internal Service Error. What are these things, and how can I fix them?

My code:

```
require "nestful"
require "sinatra"
require "uri"

get '/' do
  params = {
    :consumer_key => '******************************', 
    :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:4567/callback'
  }    

  response = Nestful.post 'https://www.getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request',
                :params => params,   
                :format => :json
 response.body
 response.headers

end

get '/callback' do
  "hello world"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got help on my problem. It turns out that `params` was already a hash, and so I did not need to say `:params => params` because that would be redundant.

### Before

```
response = Nestful.post 'https://www.getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request',
            :params => params,   
            :format => :json
```

### After

```
response = Nestful.post 'https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request',
                params,   
                :format => :json
```